# Can DOSBox emulate a machine that has two display adapters?

Tags: multiple-monitors, emulator, dosbox

I've been playing around with Borland Turbo C for reasons that I cannot explain or defend, and I noticed the following text in the online help:

```
/D: Tells Turbo C to use Dual monitor mode
(two displays). User program output is
displayed on the monitor where Turbo C was
started from, while the integrated
development environment is displayed on
the other display.
```

This got me thinking, is there any way (either in DOSBox or with another emulator stack) to reproduce the kind of environment where such a feature could work? I'm thinking it would show as two separate windows in the host OS that could be moved independently, or a single double-wide window that fits both screens within it.

Am I wishing for something impossible here?